# Deployment issue of spring with JAX-WS WAR in JBOSS

Tags: eclipse, spring, web-services, maven, jax-ws

I am using Spring, Maven and creating a web service in eclipse. While deploying the WAR in JBOSS I am getting following error-

```
Internal Server Error
{
"outcome" => "failed",
"failure-description" => {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"NextGen-web1.war\".INSTALL" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit.\"NextGen-web1.war\".INSTALL: JBAS018733: Failed to process phase INSTALL of deployment \"NextGen-web1.war\"
Caused by: javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.objectweb.asm.MethodWriter.visitLabel(org.objectweb.asm.Label)"}},
"rolled-back" => true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you must include this library in your pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>asm</groupId>
  <artifactId>asm</artifactId>
  <version>3.3.1.redhat-9</version>
</dependency>
```